# Is it possible to loop through RowDataBound?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview, progress-bar

Is it possible to capture specific iterations of RowDataBound?

```
protected void gvProposals_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
         HtmlGenericControl hgcsampleNum = gvExample.Rows[*iteration*]
            .FindControl("sample") as HtmlGenericControl;

         hgcsampleNum .Attributes.Add("style", "width: 75%; height: 20px");
    }
}
```

I have values that need to get changed dynamically for each iteration.

Comment: Have a look at [DataKeys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeys(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `e.Row.RowIndex` to find index of iteration:

```
HtmlGenericControl hgcsampleNum = gvExample.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]
            .FindControl("sample") as HtmlGenericControl;
```

Alternatively you can use `e.Row.FindControl` inside RowDataBound event:

```
HtmlGenericControl hgcsampleNum = e.Row.FindControl("sample") as HtmlGenericControl;
```

Both are same.